# Angular 2 Master/Detail nead explanation

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new in Angular 2, this is code from Official website. I understand all of class, import , list, HTML tags. But i don't understand onSelect(hero) metod. *ngFor directiv listing id and name. And if we selected list, details are displayed. How the method works? It grabs the data, but in what way it's not clear to me.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class Hero {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];

@Component({



selector: 'my-app',
```

`template:` `

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<h2>My Heroes</h2>
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
<div *ngIf="selectedHero">
  <h2>{{selectedHero.name}} details!</h2>
  <div><label>id: </label>{{selectedHero.id}}</div>
  <div>
    <label>name: </label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="selectedHero.name" placeholder="name"/>
  </div>
</div>


 `,


styles: [`
.selected {
  background-color: #CFD8DC !important;
  color: white;
}
.heroes {
  margin: 0 0 2em 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 15em;
}
.heroes li {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #EEE;
  margin: .5em;
  padding: .3em 0;
  height: 1.6em;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.heroes li.selected:hover {
  background-color: #BBD8DC !important;
  color: white;
}
.heroes li:hover {
  color: #607D8B;
  background-color: #DDD;
  left: .1em;
}
.heroes .text {
  position: relative;
  top: -3px;
}
.heroes .badge {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.8em 0.7em 0 0.7em;
  background-color: #607D8B;
  line-height: 1em;
  position: relative;
  left: -1px;
  top: -4px;
  height: 1.8em;
  margin-right: .8em;
  border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}


 `]

})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes';
  heroes = HEROES;
  selectedHero: Hero;

  onSelect(her: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = her;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following loop we're going trough each of the heroes from the HEROES array:

```
<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
    (click)="onSelect(hero)">
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
</li>
```

So each list item will represent a different hero. The id and name are displayed (using `{{hero.id}}` and `{{hero.name}}` respectively) but the `hero` represents the entire object.

So because the on click behavior is defind as:
`(click)="onSelect(hero)"` 
clicking the item will call the `onSelect` method with the hero that it represents as the parameter.

The `onSelect` method assigns the hero passed into it as parameter to the `selectedHero` field of the `AppComponent`.

In the html template you can see that the displayed name of the selected hero is defined as `{{selectedHero.name}}` which means that it takes the name value from the `selectedHero` field.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. I have more one question. In the method is bound item and displayed on other HTML with selectedHero value , like {{selectedHero.name}}? hero in (click)="onSelect(hero) is value  from *NgFor? What is "her" in  onSelect(her: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = her;
  }
 Thanks.

Comment: @StoiljkovićMiloš The "her" is the name of the parameter of the `onSelect` Method. The `onSelect(her:Hero)` definition means that the `onSelect` methods takes a single parameter (named `her`) of `Hero` type. I'm not sure if I correctly understand the rest of the question, but the Angular2 binds the properties defined in the `AppComponent` to the resulting html. So if you use the `{{selectedHero.id}}` in your html template and then change the value of `selectedHero` property in the code, the HTML view should react and display the new value.